# Swift Currency formatter for locale fr_CA

Tags: ios, swift, locale, currency, number-formatting

I am formatting my currency using locale fr_CA, I use below code to do

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_CA")
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: 33 as NSNumber) {
        print(formattedTipAmount)
    }
```

I am getting output as **33,00 $**, but my expected output as **33,00 CAD**

Do I need to manually replace last symbol($) with (CAD) or any other proper way of doing it. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to manually replace last symbol($) with (CAD)…

Yes, you do.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_CA")
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencySymbol = "CAD"
if let formattedTipAmount = formatter.string(from: 33) {
    print(formattedTipAmount)
}
```